# Odometer in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator

I am trying to implement an odometer in Rust. This should a be an iterator that yields items of type `[u16; N]` and it should be generic over const `N`.

### Configuration Parameters

The iterator should be configurable with a starting state of type `[u16; N]` which should be the value yielded on the first iteration, and a `limit` which should dictate when each element "rolls over" as described in the following section.

### Behavior description

On each iteration of the iterator, the rightmost element of the yielded item should be increased by 1 until it reaches `limit - 1` at which time it should roll over back to zero and the next leftmost element should be incremented. This process should continue until all elements are `limit - 1`, after which the iterator is exhausted and should no longer yield any elements.

This behavior is the same as that exhibited by a typical [mechanical car odometer](https://media.news4jax.com/photo/2019/08/07/Erasing_the_extra_miles_What_you_need_to_know_about_odometer_fraud_1565212793564_22160106_ver1.0_1280_720.jpg) when `limit == 10`.

It can also be thought of as an `N`-digit counter with radix `limit` which adds with integer overflow.

#### Example Outputs

An odometer iterator with initial state `[1,2,3]` and `limit = 4` should yield the following sequence:

```
[1, 2, 3] // First element yielded is the initial state
[1, 3, 0] // least significant digit rolls over here at `limit - 1 = 4`
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[1, 3, 3]
[2, 0, 0] // digit 1 and 2 both roll over here
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 3]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 0]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 3]
[3, 0, 0] // digit 1 and 2 both roll over here again
[3, 0, 1]
[3, 0, 2]
[3, 0, 3]
[3, 1, 0]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 0]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 0]
[3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 2]
[3, 3, 3] // All three digits roll over after this element so iteration stops.
```

### Naïve implementation

Here is a naïve implementation with design thought process documented as comments

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Odometer<const N: usize> {
    state: Option<[u16; N]>,
    limit: u16,
}

impl<const N: usize> Odometer<N> {
    /// Increment the odometer's internal state according to the iteration rules. When the
    /// odometer is completely exhausted, this should leave the state as None so that iteration
    /// halts on the next call to Iterator::next
    #[inline]
    fn increment(&mut self) {
        // Keep track of the number of digits that roll over during this incrementation
        let mut rollovers = 0;
        // SAFETY: Odometer::increment is only called after verifying that `self.state.is_some()`
        // so the unwrap() here is safe.
        for digit in self.state.as_mut().unwrap().iter_mut().rev() {
            // Increment this digit by 1 with modular arithmetic to implement the digit rollover
            // behavior
            *digit = (*digit + 1) % self.limit;
            if *digit != 0 {
                // If the digit is not zero after the increment it did not roll over so the state
                // is now final. return immediately
                return;
            }
            // If this line is reached a rollover has occurred on this digit, so increment the
            // rollover counter.
            rollovers += 1;
        }
        // If the number of rollovers is N, the iterator is exhausted
        if rollovers == N {
            self.state = None;
        }
    }
}

impl<const N: usize> Iterator for Odometer<N> {
    type Item = [u16; N];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // Save a copy of the initial state to return if there is one, otherwise return None early
        let initial_state = self.state?;
        // Increment the internal state according to the iteration rules
        self.increment();
        // Return the copy of the initial state saved before the call to Self::increment
        Some(initial_state)
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab35ba57480190504510a8ba8a3046d0)

Comment: *On each iteration of the iterator, the leftmost element of the yielded item should be increased by 1* but you start increasing the rightmost element...

Comment: @RichardNeumann good catch, corrected question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is easy to follow. It is structured well and well formatted. Also variables are named sensibly.

A few possible improvements below:

## Don't assume valid state

In `increment()` don't assume valid state. Check for it!

## Use comments sparingly

Currently you have a lot of comments. The only really useful comment being the one that hints on the assumption of valid state in `increment()`. You may remove the other comments as they don't clarify anything.

## Get rid of unnecessary state

Currently you track `rollovers` (usually called `carry` on additions), which is not necessary.

## Make the code more generic

You can generalize the type of stored variables using a generic type and restricting it via `num_traits`:

```
[package]
name = "odometer"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
num-traits = "0.2.18"
```

`lib.rs`:

```rust
use num_traits::{One, Zero};
use std::ops::Rem;

pub struct Odometer<const DIGITS: usize, T>
where
    T: Copy + Eq + Rem<Output = T> + One + Zero,
{
    digits: Option<[T; DIGITS]>,
    modulo: T,
}

impl<const DIGITS: usize, T> Odometer<DIGITS, T>
where
    T: Copy + Eq + Rem<Output = T> + One + Zero,
{
    pub const fn new(modulo: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            digits: None,
            modulo,
        }
    }

    /// Increment the odometer.
    ///
    /// # Errors
    /// Returns [`T::one()`] as carry on overflow.
    fn increment(&mut self) -> Result<(), T> {
        if let Some(digits) = &mut self.digits {
            increment(digits, self.modulo)
        } else {
            self.digits.replace([T::zero(); DIGITS]);
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}

impl<const DIGITS: usize, T> Iterator for Odometer<DIGITS, T>
where
    T: Copy + Eq + Rem<Output = T> + One + Zero,
{
    type Item = [T; DIGITS];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.increment().ok()?;
        self.digits
    }
}

fn increment<const DIGITS: usize, T>(digits: &mut [T; DIGITS], modulo: T) -> Result<(), T>
where
    T: Copy + Eq + Rem<Output = T> + One + Zero,
{
    for digit in digits.iter_mut().rev() {
        *digit = (*digit + T::one()) % modulo;

        if *digit != T::zero() {
            return Ok(());
        }
    }

    Err(T::one())
}
```

`main.rs`:

```rust
use odometer::Odometer;

fn main() {
    for step in Odometer::<3, u16>::new(4) {
        println!("{step:?}");
    }
}
```